# Lucene.Net what am I doing wrong?

Tags: lucene.net

I'm very new to lucene.net. I wrote this simple console app in C# which indexes some fake data. I then wanted to be able to search the index for various terms using a booleanquery.

I never get any results back. Here is the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter("Test", analyzer, true);
        Console.WriteLine("Creating index");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++)
        {
            Lucene.Net.Documents.Document doc = new Lucene.Net.Documents.Document();
            doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("A", i.ToString(), Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.NO));
            doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("B", "LALA" + i.ToString(), Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.NO));
            doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("C", "DODO" + i.ToString(), Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.NO));
            doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("D", i.ToString() + " MMMMM", Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.NO));
            writer.AddDocument(doc);
        }            
        writer.Optimize();
        writer.Close();

        BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
        query.Add(new WildcardQuery(new Term("B", "lala*")), Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        query.Add(new WildcardQuery(new Term("C", "DoDo1*")), Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher("Test");
        Hits hits = searcher.Search(query);
        if (hits.Length() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", 
                    hits.Doc(i).GetField("A").StringValue(),
                    hits.Doc(i).GetField("B").StringValue(),
                    hits.Doc(i).GetField("C").StringValue(),
                    hits.Doc(i).GetField("D").StringValue());
            }
        }
        searcher.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I then got it to work by using MultiFieldQueryParser Like so:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();            

        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter("Test", analyzer, true);
        Console.WriteLine("Creating index");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++)
        {
            Lucene.Net.Documents.Document doc = new Lucene.Net.Documents.Document();
            doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("A", i.ToString(), Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
            doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("B", "LALA" + i.ToString(), Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
            doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("C", "DODO" + i.ToString(), Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
            doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("D", i.ToString() + " MMMMM", Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
            writer.AddDocument(doc);
        }            
        writer.Optimize();
        writer.Close();            

        BooleanQuery.SetMaxClauseCount(5000);
        Query query = MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(new string[] { "LALA*", "DODO*" }, new string[] { "B", "C" }, analyzer); 

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher("Test");
        Hits hits = searcher.Search(query);
        if (hits.Length() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", 
                    hits.Doc(i).GetField("A").StringValue(),
                    hits.Doc(i).GetField("B").StringValue(),
                    hits.Doc(i).GetField("C").StringValue(),
                    hits.Doc(i).GetField("D").StringValue());
            }
        }
        searcher.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is possibly the best article I've found for any new lucene developers: http://www.ifdefined.com/blog/post/2009/02/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a problem when building your index. You add four fields to each document, all of them are stored but none of them is indexed (=> Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.NO). You should index at least on field.

Beware that the StandardAnalyzer tokenize each field index in the following way: lowercasing and splitting with common english stop words. So when building your query, use LOWERCASE prefix in order to have hits:

```
query.Add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("B", "lala")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
query.Add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("C", "dodo")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

Comment: I tokenized the A field and re-ran the app. It still did not return any results.

Comment: Any other suggestions? Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: You can only perform a search on indexed fields. So you also have to index "B" and "C" fields.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I changed them to all be indexed, however I now get an error TooManyClauses was unhandled. I'm busy reading up about it. This post may point me in the right direction: http://sanjayakumar.blogspot.com/2008/10/lucene-free-text-search-engine.html, Thanks for you help.

Comment: That works better then the solution I found with the MultiFieldQueryParser, thanks once again!

Comment: Over a decade later, Lucene.NET's latest version has been "beta" for years, the documentation is terrible and cryptic, and 'Field' is deprecated. Needed to use 'TextField' instead of 'StringField' to have the values tokenized & show up with a Search query. That tip still helped!